# ending block elements on the same vertical line; fixing double outlines

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML/CSS code I'm having two issues:

1. The `result` class boxes have double sized outlines on the top, left, and bottom.
2. The `group` class elements stretch off past the right side of the screen.

What can I change to make all the block elements end cleanly on the right-side of the screen and give them all 1px outlines?

Thanks,
PaulH

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>   
    <style type="text/css">
    .result
    {
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        outline: 1px solid #98BF21;

        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #98BF21;

        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;

        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;

        width: 70px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .group
    {
        border: 1px solid #98BF21;
        background-color: #EEFFCC;
        position:relative;
        left: 72px;
    }

    .summary
    {
        outline: 1px solid #98BF21;

        color: #333333;
        background-color: #EEFFCC;

        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: "Lucida Console","courier new";

        line-height: 25px;
    }

    .summary p
    {
        padding-left: 7px;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .detail
    {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-family: "Lucida Console","courier new";
    }

    .detail p
    {
        padding-left: 7px;
        margin: 5px 0px;
        white-space: pre;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="summary"><span class="result">esse &#xFE3E</span><p>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</p></div>
<div class="group">
    <span class="detail">
        <p>labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
    </span>
    <div class="summary"><span class="result">esse »</span><p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

*Edit:*
I'm using Firefox 4.0B12. For whatever reason IE8 doesn't show the double outlines.

*Edit2:*
The desired output would be something like this. Single, non-overlapping outlines all ending at the same point on the right-side of the screen.

```
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| esse | consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
       | labore et dolore magna aliqua                                     |
       +------+------------------------------------------------------------+
       | esse | Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation         |
       +------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**change:** left: 72px;
**to:** margin-left: 72px;

Can you provide more details about the lines, or maybe an image of what you want it to look like.

Comment: I've added some ASCII art to the bottom of the question. Changing to `margin-left` fixed the issue of the lines not ending at the same place on the right side of the screen. Thank you. Any suggestions on the other problem of having 2px thick outlines?